# Really old PCs- boot from CD

Tags: linux, boot

I tried searching for info on this, if you know of a current thread please redirect.

Here is the thing:

I have a really old computer. It is from a school and running Windows NT.
The plan is to remove Windows and put a very lightweight Linux distro.

The problem is as follows: (I am using a Ubuntu live disk)
I go to the boot manager and have the option to use Floppy, PXE, Hard drive. I put the hard drive last, the CD drive is not accessed since Ubuntu live CD isn't launched.

Further, the problem is that, when I get into Windows NT it has everything disabled, cannot use command prompt, cannot access CD drive etc... all permissions taken away.

I need some advice on what do to as far as getting around this. Further, I was wondering of a very small Linux distro that has little to no GUI. just terminal would be best.

Comment: oh dear, HOW old? if CDROM is not an option in the BIOS the CDROM drive is possibly connected to an ATA interface on the sound card.

Comment: @Molly: he did say "running WinNT" not "running Win2000" or "running WinXP"... we can only __pray__ he means NT 4, and not ... NT 3.5...

Answer (score 4):

One way to fix this is to use: *SmartBootManager*. You use a Windows utility that has been floating around ~~forever, called `rawrite`, to write a `sbm.bin` to the floppy. It can then handle booting the CD. Or, just use a random Linux system and `dd(1)` sbm to the floppy.

See the [Ubuntu SmartBootManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SmartBootManager) page.

Alternatively, you could install a system like [NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org/) that still has a floppy-based installer, but it isn't that much easier.

Answer (score 4):

I've used PXE to boot the Debian installer before on machines which didn't seem able to boot from CD or USB.  Details [here](http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/i386/apas02.html.en#howto-getting-images-netboot).  You'll need another LAN machine to host a tftp and DCHP server.  Once you've got a few installs via PXE under your belt you'll start thinking it's actually easier than burning a CD, since it can be done entirely online (download images, untar to tftp server, config DHCP, power-up client...).

You don't necessarily need a special lightweight distro (unless you have a truly pitiful amount of [memory](http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/i386/ch02s05.html.en) or a fossil of a [processor](http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/i386/ch02s01.html.en#id2756691)); Debian can be a good fit to old hardware if you don't select the installer's desktop profile (all of Gnome and KDE).  Post-install, just manually install xorg and (say) fluxbox and whatever apps you think are lightweight enough.

Comment: You may want to give Tiny Core Linux a shot. I have been very happy with the performance of it, and it has a lot of the modern niceties that sometimes get dropped from micro distros. http://tinycorelinux.com/

Comment: Or try Haiku -- http://www.haiku-os.org/